# "gcloud app deploy" hangs on "Building and pushing image for service"

Tags: google-app-engine

I suddenly can't deploy using gcloud app deploy.

It hangs on "Building and pushing image for service [default]". At that time, the Python process takes 99% CPU, and continues until the deploy times out. I've tried upgrading Python to no avail.

It occurs regardless of Google Appengine Project. Have tried installing different versions of gcloud CLI to no avail.

My teammates can deploy successfully using the same commands. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share more details about this issue? Some steps to reproduce and files that you may find helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete the local project, and clone the apparently identical branch again from Github.

This has happened twice. Quite mysterious.